# jQuery before() outputting as string rather than HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to inject some HTML before an input on Gravity Forms using some simple jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
var formInputs = jQuery( "form li input" )

formInputs.each(function( index ) {
  this.before('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>');
});
```

Here is what it looks like on each input

[image]

Is there some form of conflict with Gravity Forms?

**EDIT**: I tried replacing

```
this.before('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>');
```

with

`this.before(jQuery('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'));`

and instead I get jQuery object

[image]

Comment: Try `this.before(jQuery('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'));`

Comment: @CameronHurd thanks for suggestion, please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
jQuery('<h1>Hello World!</h1>').insertBefore(this);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r181ohtj/

Comment: Screwed up the link at first. Fixed.

Comment: He want to escape the HTML and output it as plain text not as HTML.

Comment: @KhorshedAlam nono Sean got it right. Trying to inject HTML.

Comment: That's what the jsfiddle is doing. It's creating an H1 as html.

Comment: @Sean Curious though, any ideas why `.insertBefore()` works and `.before()` doesn't?

Comment: @softcode I think it was actually the way he was starting it that was an issue. Because this works as well. https://jsfiddle.net/r181ohtj/2/

Answer (score 3):

`this` inside a `jQuery.each()` method refers to the JavaScript object not the jQuery object of that element, so if you want to use any jQuery method on that element you've to wrap it with jQuery.

```
var formInputs = jQuery( "form li input" )

formInputs.each(function( index ) {
  jQuery(this).before( document.createTextNode('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>') );
});
```

And if you want to escape the html and output as plain text then `document.createTextNode` method can help you. Update your code to following.

```
var formInputs = jQuery( "form li input" )

formInputs.each(function( index ) {
  jQuery(this).before( document.createTextNode('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>') );
});
```